# Bulk sending button in #Salesforce to use #DocuSignAPI?

Tags: docusignapi

Has anyone created a bulk sending button in #Salesforce to use #DocuSignAPI?

I would like to add a custom button on a Contact List View in Salesforce that will allow Bulk Sending of templates/envelopes in DocuSign.

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign for Salesforce (DfS) does not support Bulk Sending, which means you can not use the DfS App to do Bulk Sending.  To accommodate this use-case you would need to write your own custom DocuSign API integration.  If you're interested in that route check out the [DocuSign Developer Center](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center).

Answer (score 0):

You could also export your contact list and data to a csv file to do a bulk send via the Web Application.  Connect could then be updated to get envelope updates back to the contacts in Salesforce.